# what is the definition of findind Global and Local maxima in a image

Tags: image-processing

I need to find Global and Local Maxima in an image to perform the next operatio (GM-AverageLocalMaxima)^2. I am using Opencv 3, bu ti think my real problem is that I don't understand the concept of Global and Local Maxima.

Comment: The Global maximum is the highest/brightest pixel in the entire image. A Local one is any one that is brighter than all its nearby neighbours.

Comment: @MarkSetchell but doesnt "maxima" make that plural? So it's brightest pixel**s**. Dunno though I dont use OpenCV but I guess a threshold level is involved?.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I think now the concept is more clear for me.  I really appreciatte.